# How to determine the number of the input arguments in Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

Is there some methods to determine the number of input arguments from console in Java.
Or just compare args[i] to null?

Answer (score 8):

How about using `args.length` ?

Comment: @Pangea: Yeah noticed that and updated as fast as I can before someone down votes.

Answer (score 4):

In `public static void main(String[] args)`, `args` is an array. You can get the number of elements of an (any) array in Java with `args.length`. If there are no arguments, the array will have length 0, and `args[0]` will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: don't forget to always check if its null first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `args.length` to count the arguments.
You could use a library like [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) to parse the arguments.

Comment: `args` will never be null. If no arguments are specified it will have a length of 0.